# How can I create a jollyday HolidayManager instance from a given Locale?

Tags: java

In my application the user can set her `Locale` from a list of available locales. The application needs to determine if a given date is a holiday and I am using [jollyday](https://github.com/svendiedrichsen/jollyday) for this task.

Here is my current code:

```
public boolean isHoliday(Calendar cal) {
    HolidayManager m = HolidayManager.getInstance();
    return m.isHoliday(cal);
}
```

I can change this to the following code to set a specific `HolidayCalendar`:

```
public boolean isHoliday(Calendar cal) {
    HolidayManager m = HolidayManager.getInstance(HolidayCalendar.GERMANY);
    return m.isHoliday(cal);
}
```

But this method is deprecated and I would need to figure out which `HolidayCalendar` I need based on the user locale. What I want to do is something like this:

```
public boolean isHoliday(Calendar cal, Locale loc) {
    HolidayManager m = HolidayManager.getInstance(loc);
    return m.isHoliday(cal);
}
```

I know that `HolidayManager` is using `Locale.getDefault()` and there are public methods in `Holiday` too (see [here](https://github.com/svendiedrichsen/jollyday/blob/master/src/main/java/de/jollyday/Holiday.java#L109)) but I can not figure out how to do this and the documentation is very brief.

My question: Can I get the holidays based on a particular locale? Do I have to write a major `switch` statement for all the locales to match a `HolidayCalendar`?

*Update* I created [a PR to the project](https://github.com/svendiedrichsen/jollyday/pull/39) and added the functionality myself. The PR already got merged

Comment: I would suggest that you contact the team behind that 3rd party, off-site resource. Instead of asking an off-topic question here (and even if it would be "on topic" I guess your chances of getting answers here are pretty small).

Comment: @GhostCat There are already a couple questions about Jollyday on SO and it looks like the author is responding. I do think that questions about java+holidays are common enough to keep the question. I'll close it if it gets downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

In the `jollyday/util/ResourceUtil.java` I see a hashmap for locale-holiday_description pair, but it's private static and not being populated anywhere.

https://github.com/svendiedrichsen/jollyday/blob/master/src/main/java/de/jollyday/util/ResourceUtil.java#L61

```
private static final Map<Locale, ResourceBundle> HOLIDAY_DESCRIPTION_CACHE = new HashMap<>();
```

So, I believe, there isn't any direct method to do what you are looking for. And it would default to default Locale as you figured out. But you can fork and modify that package to your needs and use it in your code.

Also, trying opening a issue-request https://github.com/svendiedrichsen/jollyday/issues